# Show that $\lim_{x\to 0^{+} }x\Gamma(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is taken from Bartle's Elements of Real Analysis. The purpose of the exercise is to show that the gamma function is not bounded to the right of $x=0$. So what I have to show is:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt=1$$

I am not sure how to handle this limit though. Any hints/suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You can use or prove [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) and deduce it from there. Or since this is targeting only the pole at $0$, probably just doing one integration by parts is enough.

Comment: Can you use that $x\Gamma(x) = \Gamma(x+1)$?

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll use that instead. Thanks, @MartinR